# Loading, please wait message doesn't hide after the data has been loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I have this bootstrap-table data table, and after all the data are loaded, the message continues to display. Anyone has any idea why this is happenning? Thank you in advance.

```
<table class='table table-striped table-hover' id='main_table' data-url={{ db_json }} data-click-to-select='true' data-filter-control="true" clickToSelect='true'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-checkbox="true" data-checkbox-enabled="true"></th>
          <th data-field="ID" data-visible="false">Id</th>
          <th data-field="data1" data-filter-control="input">data1</th>
          <th data-field="data2" data-filter-control="select">data2</th>
          <th data-field="data3" data-filter-control="select">data3</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: what are you using here? can you provide a working fiddle with 'db_json' data?

Comment: it may be a problem with JQuery.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same problem, the solution I found was to include the css file from bootstraptable on the head section of the html file.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
</head>
```

also  if you are working with the local files, do not forget to refer to the `bootstrap-table.min.css` file.

Comment: That solved my issue as well. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was overriding Bootstrap´s CSS with my own. In a `yourname.css` file that has to be declared in HEAD **after** the Bootstrap CSS link, include this:

```
.fixed-table-loading {
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
}

.loading-wrap {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}

.table-loading {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}

.loading {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

This prevents the div that contains the "*Loading, please wait*" from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just solved. My problem is that I added media

At first I used this, which was ok.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
```

Then I save the file to my local

```
<link  href="{{ asset('ocadmin-asset/stylesheet/bootstrap-table-1.21.2.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Nothing wrong on screen, but when printing, the loading message appears.  This is because media="screen" should not exist.